# Unexpected result when subtracting floats

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby floating point errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055618/ruby-floating-point-errors)

In Ruby, when subtracting 4.7 from 5.0, I would expect a result of 0.3 but get:

```
~ $ irb
1.9.2p290 :001 > 5.0 - 4.7
 => 0.2999999999999998
```

I'm guessing there is a reason for this rather than it being a bug? Using `BigDecimal` objects yields the same result. Is my only option to use `round` on the result?

Comment: Ah, using BigDecimal with a string as the parameter gets me what I want: `(BigDecimal.new('5.0') - BigDecimal('4.7')).to_f`, but not `(BigDecimal.new(5.0, 0) - BigDecimal(4.7, 0)).to_f`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floats lose precision. Nothing can be done about that. So, use:

```
(5.0 - 4.7).round(1)
```

and if you had needed more precision:

```
(0.50 - 0.47).round(2)
```

Comment: Figured I'd need to do this, thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. It's how floating point arithmetics works. More details here: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I knew it was _something_ to do with how Float works, but not exactly why. Will give it a read.