# Ruby subsecond time addition incorrect

Tags: ruby, time

I am having an issue with adding floating point numbers to time in ruby.  In the example below, how is t2 not equal to 2013-02-15T01:17:17.996000000?

```
irb(main):094:0> t1.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N")
=> "2013-02-15T01:16:47.785000000"
irb(main):095:0> t2 = t1 + 30.211
=> 2013-02-15 01:17:17 -0700
irb(main):096:0> t2.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N")
=> "2013-02-15T01:17:17.995999999"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mainly about floating-point arithmetic.

Try `1.4 - 1.3` in the ruby shell.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: The answer is as correct as it's ever going to be.

Comment: Good article to explain, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed before. You should check the following thread: 
[ruby floating point errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055618/ruby-floating-point-errors)