# Different results from ruby floating-point expressions

Tags: ruby

What is difference between Case 1 and Case 2?

I think the result should be the same: 7.78

Can someone explain to me?

Case 1： `a=(x/y).round(4)*100`

Case 2： `a=(x/y*100).round(2)`

Case 1

```
x=7.0
y=90
a=x/y
=> 0.07777777777777778
a=a.round(4)
=> 0.0778
a=a*100
=> 7.779999999999999
```

Case 2

```
x=7.0
y=90
a=x/y
=> 0.07777777777777778
a=a*100
=> 7.777777777777778
a=a.round(2)
=> 7.78
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055618/ruby-floating-point-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, this leads to many surprising situations.

I advise to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems