# 110/1.1 != 100 floating point issue?

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Any thoughts as to that for which I had not accounted here?

Looks like it returns `99.99999999999999`

using ruby 2.3.1p112

Comment: The answer is in your title. `100-110/1.1` outputs `1.42e-14`, which is probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

[This was discussed million times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055618/ruby-floating-point-errors) - to have precise calculations one ***must*** use decimal data type, which in Ruby is represented by [`BigDecimal`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) class:

```
BigDecimal(110)/1.1 == 100
#=> true
```

Comment: Your summary of the million discussions is very approximative. Decimal is not inherently more accurate than binary. Decimal floating-point is better than binary floating-point for decimal numbers, and multiprecision is better than machine arithmetic, but that does not make BigDecimal the panacea that you imply it to be.